# azure devops npm task

Tags: npm, azure-devops, npm-run

I am currently using npm task in my build pipeline in azure devops.
Recently the npm run step started failing with below error. When I manually install the sass and sass-loader the npm run step passes without any error. How can I install the complete modules from pipeline.?

**ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):**

Comment: Please share your pipeline with us and if possible package.json.

Comment: have you tried set binary configuration parameters like `SASS_BINARY_SITE`? https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters

`node-sass` is difficult especially when you are run npm install against a mirror registry or behind a proxy etc

Comment: Can i set from the pipeline to install the sass modules?

Comment: yeah, it can be done in process parameter, or in your .npmrc, or simply environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by adding another step with npm task and passed and argument(sass-loader) to install the sass modules.

Comment: Hi @priyankach, thanks for sharing this answer. Could you please mark this answer as the solution of this topic? So that other people can notice this solution more quickly when they are viewing this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways to see if the problem can be solved:

1. Execute the **`npm install`** command to install the **node-sass** (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)) in the pipeline.

   ```sh
   npm install -D node-sass
   ```
2. Reconfigure your npm package on the local machine.

   - Install or upgrade **Angular** to the latest version.
   - Check out the source repository to the local machine.
   - Remove the nose modules and the package lock.
   - Reinstall the refresh dependencies for your package via the **`npm isntall`** command.
   - Push the changes to the remote repository, then try the pipeline.

Comment: The  npm install task is already in my pipeline before the npm run step. But the  task isnt installing the sass modules. How can I mention to add the sass modules too from the npm install step?

Comment: Hi @priyankach, how about executing the `npm install` command using a shell task (e.g. `Bash`, `PowerShell`, etc.), instead of the `npm install` task?

Comment: Thanks for your replies . I have fixed the issue by adding another step with npm task and passed and argument(sass-loader) to install the sass modules.

Comment: Hi @priyankach, glad that you have solved the problem. If possible, could you please post an answer to share the details of your solution? This may be very helpful to more people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions. Thanks.